# oracle plsql select all column (single row) and return as json

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have a simple table (not JSON strict). I want to write a simple function that takes employee id as parameter and return all columns from the table that matches the id. My function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST AS

FUNCTION SEARCH_JOINING_INFO(EMP_ID VARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB IS
    RET TBL_EMP_BASIC_PROFILE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO RET FROM TBL_EMP_BASIC_PROFILE WHERE TBL_EMP_BASIC_PROFILE.EMP_ID=EMP_ID;
    --RETURN RET.GETCLOBVAL();
END;

END PKG_TEST;
```

This obviously doesn't work at all. I want to select a single row(all columns) and return it as string in json format. for example, `'{"EMP_ID" : "1234", "EMP_NAME" : "ABC"}'` like this. But I don't know how. Besides, I want to use ' **SELECT *** ' format, because sometimes I may need to add new columns. How can I do it? Is there any way available?
My table description:

```
Name                 Null     Type          
-------------------- -------- ------------- 
EMP_ID               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(13)  
EMP_NAME                      VARCHAR2(50)  
EMP_NAME_BANG                 VARCHAR2(150) 
EMP_GENDER                    NUMBER(1)     
EMP_CATEGORY                  NUMBER(1)     
EMP_OFFICE                    NUMBER(7)     
EMP_DESIGNATION               NUMBER(4)     
EMP_DATE_OF_JOINING           DATE          
EMP_GRADE                     NUMBER(2)     
EMP_SLAB                      NUMBER(2)     
EMP_BASIC                     NUMBER(7)     
EMP_PHOTO_UPLOAD              VARCHAR2(500) 
CREATED_ON                    DATE          
CREATED_BY                    VARCHAR2(10)  
EMP_BIRTH_DATE                DATE          
EMP_EMAIL                     VARCHAR2(50)  
EMP_PHONE                     VARCHAR2(15)  
EMP_ACCOUNT_NO                VARCHAR2(50)  
EMP_BANK_NAME                 VARCHAR2(50)  
EMP_APPOINTMENT_TYPE          NUMBER(1)
```